# What is the pill shaped mini frame showing up above where is touch on iphone after double click , and how to disable it?

Tags: ios, iphone

When I double tap, I get this weird pill shaped mini display that shows what my finger touches (without maginifying it or anything). Scrolling does not work while it is displayed. What's the point of it, and can I disable it in my PWA application?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can provide a partial answer to your question. This pill shaped view essentially shows the user what is under their finger / thumb. It aids in text selection (for copying certain parts of text), or cursor placement while editing text.
The other part about the question regarding whether you can disable it in your PWA, I am not sure, but essentially this is default webview behaviour. I hope someone can help you out with this, or maybe you’re able to figure this out.